# How to memoize a component that uses hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to convert a HOC to a hook. My current HOC basically consumes a context, and pass the data as props to the wrapped component. Just like this:

```
import React from "react";

import BadgesCountersContext from "../../../contexts";

const withBadgesCounters = (Component) => (props) => {
  return (
    <ContentsContext.Consumer>
      {(badgesCounters) => <Component {...props} badgesCounters={badgesCounters} />}
    </ContentsContext.Consumer>
  );
};

export default withBadgesCounters;
```

I am using it in components, like this:

```
const MyComponent = memo((props) => {
   ... 
}, (prevProps, nextProps) => {
   return prevProps.badgesCounters["badgeName"] === 
       nextProps.badgesCounters["badgeName"];
});

export default withBadgesCounters(MyComponent);
```

As badgesCounters is a map, which have the following form:

```
{
   badgeName1: 10,
   badgeName2: 3,
   ...
}
```

I am memoizing the component, to avoid re-renders when other badges that doesn't interest the component changes.

How can I do the same with a hook?

I have just created the following one:

```
import { useContext } from "react";

import BadgesCountersContext from "../contexts/";

export default function useBadgesCounters() {
  const context = useContext(BadgesCountersContext);

  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error("Cannot find BadgesCountersContext");
  }

  return context;
}
```

But, it seems that I can't memoize the component as I am not receiving the data as prop.